# Batch SQL inserts in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Is using the .NET DataAdapter's batch insert features any more efficient, as far as DB round-trips, compared to using DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in a loop?

Coming from the Java world, I was hoping to find something similar to it's batch abilities where multiple SQL commands are sent to the database and executed in one operation.  When monitoring the database server, I see the DataAdapter making one execute per insert.

I've read a few topics that use the SqlBulkCopy but that's only going to work for MS Sql Server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DataAdapter has a UpdateBatchSize property. Setting the UpdateBatchSize to a positive integer value causes updates to the database to be sent as batches of the specified size.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is the only level that supports command batching. You may not batch your own DbCommands (without exposing some internal classes with Reflection).

Comment: I've tried this. On MS SQL Server, SQL Profiler shows each insert statement seems to be on it's own. After reviewing your comment, I viewed a TCP Dump of the conversation and do see that it is batching multiple commands together. SQL Profiler shows each insert as a "RPC Completed" event which was confusing me.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What about:
One statement multiple rows

```
mysql:
INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3)

mssql:
INSERT INTO table (id)
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3
```

Comment: I was worried that this (string concatting to make up the insert statements) would open me up to sql injection, so I was using the command object and parameters to clean input. Otherwise I could do several INSERT table VALUES() terminated by a ';' or as you had suggested.
Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: If your using this as part of a webapp then you shouldn't use it. Most of the time these batch ops. are used in db updates and stuff like that.